# What is the fastest way for executing three nested for loop?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, parallel-processing, gpu

I am an image processing programmer and I’m using opencv C++. As a part of a program that I wrote, I have three nested for. The first one is for different images, the second one is for rows of images and the third one is for columns of images. There is not any dependency between three for and they can excecute parallel (I mean, all pixels of all images can be processed in parallel). I’m not familiar with parallel programming, GPU programming, thread, tbb, parallel for loop and … . I found the different links over the internet that suggested such things. I want to know what is the fastest solution for my problem?
My OS is windows and I’m using visual studio 2015.

My code is in the following:

```
int prjResCol[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROJECTOR];
int prjResRow[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROJECTOR];
Mat prjCamCor[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROJECTOR][2]
Mat prjImgColored[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROJECTOR];

for (int i = 0; i < numOfProjector; i++)
{
    Mat tmp(prjResRow[i], prjResCol[i], CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    prjImgColored[i] = tmp;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < prjResRow[i]; ii++)
    {
        double* ptrPrjCamIAnd0 = prjCamCor[i][0].ptr<double>(ii);
        double* ptrPrjCamIAnd1 = prjCamCor[i][1].ptr<double>(ii);
        Vec3b* ptrPrjImgColoredI = prjImgColored[i].ptr<Vec3b>(ii);

        for (int jj = 0; jj < prjResCol[i]; jj++)
        {

            if ((ptrPrjCamIAnd0[jj] != NAN_VALUE) && (ptrPrjCamIAnd1[jj] != NAN_VALUE))
            {
                ptrPrjImgColoredI[jj] = secondImgColored.at<Vec3b>(ptrPrjCamIAnd1[jj], ptrPrjCamIAnd0[jj]);
            }

        }
    }
    imwrite(mainAdr + "\\img" + to_string(i) + ".bmp", prjImgColored[i]);
}
```

Comment: Try providing an MCVE - a small but COMPLETE sample.  You've left out critical information about types (`Mat,` `Vec3b`) several variables (like the ones whos names start with `prj`), and `CV_8UC3` (whatever that is).  That information is critical because, to optimise your code, someone would need to understand what those things are.

Comment: Have you profiled it? What are your constraints? How many images? What size? Which processing in the inner loop? It doesn't make sense to start "optimizing" without knowing this.

Comment: The maximum number of image are 20. each Mat size are about 2000*3000(rows*columns).

Comment: With 20 images the first "for" is not a problem. Images that size can be processed very fast without custom optimization. It all depends on what you do on your images. The internals loop you wrote are almost as fast as they can be. Profile them, show some processing time, and we'll see what can be done

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote using a Parallel For loop for iterating over the pixels would be the fastest way for large images. There is some overhead when utilizing a parallel algorithm so for a small image (say 256 X 256) you may be better off with the tradition loop you posted.

Below is an example written in Visual C++:

```
// Calls the provided function for each pixel in a Bitmap object.
void ProcessImage(Bitmap* bmp, const function<void (DWORD&)>& f)
{
   int width = bmp->GetWidth();
   int height = bmp->GetHeight();

   // Lock the bitmap.
   BitmapData bitmapData;
   Rect rect(0, 0, bmp->GetWidth(), bmp->GetHeight());
   bmp->LockBits(&rect, ImageLockModeWrite, PixelFormat32bppRGB, &bitmapData);

   // Get a pointer to the bitmap data.
   DWORD* image_bits = (DWORD*)bitmapData.Scan0;

   // Call the function for each pixel in the image.
   parallel_for (0, height, [&, width](int y)
   {      
      for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
      {
         // Get the current pixel value.
         DWORD* curr_pixel = image_bits + (y * width) + x;

         // Call the function.
         f(*curr_pixel);
      }
   });

   // Unlock the bitmap.
   bmp->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);
}
```

Another approach you can take it to parallelze your work flow where you are doing a single threaded (double for loop) iteration on several images simultaneously.  Below is an example written in in C#. You just need to substitute your serial double for loop for the bitmap flip routine.  A C++ implementation should be very similar using the proper parallel library:

// A simple source for demonstration purposes. Modify this path as necessary.
        String[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg");
        String newDir = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Modified";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newDir);

```
    // Method signature: Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
    // Be sure to add a reference to System.Drawing.dll.
    Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) => 
    {
        // The more computational work you do here, the greater 
        // the speedup compared to a sequential foreach loop.
        String filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(currentFile);

        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(newDir, filename));

        // Peek behind the scenes to see how work is parallelized.
        // But be aware: Thread contention for the Console slows down parallel loops!!!

         Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
         //close lambda expression and method invocation
         });
```

Open CV supports parallel For from at least version 2.4.3.  By using a parallel loop you can leverage the power of your multi core CPU where each core will iterate over a separate subsection of the image.

OpenCV also supports CUDA which is a parallel processing API created by NVIDA which leverages the power of your GPU.  I don't think this approach is the way to go to this particular problem but since you mention you are an image processing programmer its worth looking into for future problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The maximum number of image are 20. each Mat size are about 2000*3000(rows*columns).

Comment: Parallel for is basically useless for this kind of processing, with so few images.

Comment: Though 20 images of 6Million pixels is rather small, Parallel processing could  still cut the processing time (taking into account the slight overhead) if implemented correctly. If one is using for example an Intel I7 processing (8 Cores), and is performing a parallel workflow. (processing several images in parallel), you will see a time improvement if the PC is not being pushed to do any other intensive tasks.. I haven't tried this pattern on images, but I've done it with processing several 100 M Byte files and the time savings is really significant compared to a serial workflow.

Comment: @user3822376 - you are welcome.  I added more on the two patterns you can try with a Parallel For loop.  In addition I found some source code which should make your life easier.  Good luck!

Comment: @DaveS First of all, thank you for taking the time to write this code! I'm not familiar with Visual C++ language and I can't interpret your code. Do you mean I should change my code?

Comment: @Shahab -  I don't have openCV on my system but I did a search and I see that its Parallel Library is quite similar to Microsoft's C++/C#.  What I suggest is to check out the Parallel For examples for OpenCV. Ther are many links you can check out.  After you get a feel for it you should be able to easily use the examples I posted.  If you do implement your routine in Parallel For, I would be very interested to hear how much of speed increase you get.  Here is one link I found. There are many more you can Google - http://answers.opencv.org/question/9370/parallel-for/